# How to get day's name from date format 'yyyy-mm-dd'?

Tags: javascript, datetime, dayofweek

How can I get the day's name by giving the date format  'yyyy-mm-dd' ?

I have this date `'2015-03-03'` which is in the [correct format](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for the 
`new Date(dateString);` constructor.

How do I get the day's name which is Tuesday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely getting the wrong day of the week because of time zone off sets. You can correct this by multiplying the local time-zone offset in minutes by the number of milliseconds in a minute.

```js
var getDayOfWeek = (function () {
  var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday',
              'Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];
  return function (date) {
    return days[date.getDay()];  
  };
}());

function getLocalizedDate(dateStr) {
  var d = new Date(dateStr);
  return new Date(d.getTime() + d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
}

function daysInMarch() {
    var display = document.querySelector('#display'),
        i = 1,
        dateStr, date, formatted;

    for (; i <= 31; i++) {
        dateStr = '2015-03-' + (i < 10 ? '0' + i : i),
        date = getLocalizedDate(dateStr),
        formatted = 'March ' + date.getDate() + ' 2015 was a ';
  
        display.innerHTML += formatted +  getDayOfWeek(date) + '<br />';  
    }
}

daysInMarch();
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you , you can check my other solution I found below.

Comment: @WissemAchour indeed it is a fine solution if you are already using `moment.js`. However it can be overkill to include an entire library for a single function call.

Comment: yes you are right but fortunately I use this .js file in my project in other things.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution of this question so i wanted to share with it you guys,to get the day's name using the date format 'yyyy-mm-dd' you have to use the javascript file moment.js and use this function to get all the day's information:

```
var dayInformation = String(moment('2015-03-10'));
```

Comment: This is a fine solution if you are already using `moment.js`

Answer (score 1):

Already got this snippet that I wrote yesterday. Might be usefull for you.

```
 /**
 * Created by jjansen on 09-Mar-15 4:56 PM.
 * stackoverflow
 */
var dateName = function ( yyyy, mm, dd ) {
    var monthNames = [
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
        "June",
        "July",
        "August",
        "September",
        "October",
        "November",
        "December"
    ];

    var dayNames = [
        "Monday",
        "Thuesday",
        "Wednesday",
        "Thursday",
        "Friday",
        "Saturday",
        "Sunday"
    ];
    var today = new Date( yyyy, mm-1, dd );
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var dayname = dayNames[today.getDay()-1];
    var mm = monthNames[today.getMonth()];
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    var fullDate = dayname + " " + dd + " " + mm + " " + yyyy;

    alert( "the current date is: " + fullDate );
};

dateName( 2015, 06, 02 );
```

You can change this any way you want and it works flawless

---

http://jsfiddle.net/vuob3L16/